# QCommandLinkButton text and icon position style with QSS

Tags: qt, qpushbutton, qtstylesheets

I want to customize a `QCommandLinkButton` using `QSS` and I want to customize to widget's icon position and text position. Is this possible? I couldn't find anything on the web or on the [QSS Reference Documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/stylesheet-examples.html) although the widget can be styled. I tried the `width` and `height` properties and they do work. I think all the properties that work on `QPushButton` work also on `QCommandLinkButton` as `QCommandLinkButton` inherits `QPushButton`.

I tried

```
QCommandLinkButton::text {
    left: 10px;
}


QCommandLinkButton::icon {
    left: 10px;
}
```

but no effect.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible yet (speaking as of Qt 5.3.1).
In order to achieve this you have to derive the class and reimplement the paintEvent.